# Long running background PHP script blocks other PHP pages until it is finished

Tags: php, session, background-process

I made a long script in PHP as such:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

It runs perfectly in the background even if I close the page. My problem is that I can't open other PHP files until this script finishes running in the background. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this script plus the pages that get locked use sessions?

Comment: Until the long script is running, or until it is finished running?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes my files are using sessions, is that problem?

Comment: @cegfault Sorry for my english, so I cant use other php files while the long script is running. I hope you understand what I try to say.

Comment: Please post the code that is using the sessions; that is most likely where the problem is

Comment: @SalmanA Thank you very much! I tried without session_start() and now everything works fine. If you write an answer I'll accept yours, because you were the first one.

Comment: How can we make it work with session,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When a PHP script uses sessions, PHP locks the session file until the script completes. A page request that tries to use a locked session is blocked until the session file is released. PHP does this so that sessions remains in a consistent state. [Quote from PHP bug #31464](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31464):

> [2005-01-10 08:13 UTC] derick at php dot net
>
> This is indeed not a bug at all, the session extension needs to lock
>   the session file so that concurrent updates can not corrupt the file.
>   This means that all scripts using the same session file needs to be
>   serialized. To improve performance you can use
>   http://php.net/session_write_close as soon as you are done
>   reading/setting session variables, which will remove the lock of the
>   file.

The simplest workaround as described above and [here as well](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/) is:

- call `session_start()`
- read/write any session variables
- call `session_write_close()`
- do lengthy processing

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in comments, Sessions are the problem - this is because the session file is locked.

Use [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/session-write-close) in your long-running script to unlock the session file, but note that you cannot use `$_SESSION` variables in that particular script afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kolink, I offered to accept SalmanA's answer if he wants to write one because he was the first. Other cases I'll accept your answer.