# Is there any way to disable session for some controllers in symfony 2?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, session

Currently I am trying to close session at the start of action, because this is an AJAX action, that does not need any session at all.

```
protected function _closeSession(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasSession()){
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->save();
    }
}

public function listAction(Request $request, $mode, $id)
{
    $data = [];
    $this->_closeSession($request);
    //perform long polling

    //return json response
    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

But I get this error from NativeSessionStorage: Failed to start the session because headers have already been send.

UPDATE:

The problem is that I have 2 separate ajax calls, one for adding comments to site, and another, long-running script that is shows those comments on page via trick called long-polling. But there is a problem, when second script is blocking the first, because both are using sessions by default. This problem is described here - [Long running background PHP script blocks other PHP pages until it is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651195/long-running-background-php-script-blocks-other-php-pages-until-it-is-finished) . And I found a solution to call session_write_close manually instead of $session->save() in _closeSession. But are there any other, more Symfony-style ways to do that?

Comment: Can you explain us a bit more the idea behind killing off the session? Why is `AJAX` is so special?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need authentication to those controllers, maybe this should be a workaround.

In `security.yml` (sf 3.4):

```
firewalls:
    # disables session creation for assets controller
    assets:
        pattern: ^/assets
        stateless: true
        security: false
```