# PHP: How to check if session_start will block or make it time out

Tags: php, session

In a certain instance I want to cancel calls of users that already have an open session.
I use `session_start` to make sure, a logged in user can only execute one request at a time and that works fine. But all subsequent calls will simply block indefinitely until all previous calls went through which is unsatisfying in certain circumstances like misbehaving users.

Normally all blocking calls I know have a timeout parameter you give with them. Is there something like this for start_session?

Or is there a call in the spirit of `session_opened_by_other_script` that I can do before calling `session_start`?

Comment: I would love to know how you are doing this blocking. Always eager to learn something. So can you show us some code

Comment: Shouldn't you rather take care to close the session elsewhere before you attempt long-running tasks…?

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHP's standard session mechanism does that all by itself. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13651195/476

Comment: @deceze I want the calls to be serialized.

Comment: @deceze Ahh now I understand what OP is saying. :) Silly me!

Comment: _“to make sure, a logged in user can only execute one request at a time”_ - what exactly is that supposed to mean, and why is it important in the first place? We are probably not talking about “exactly simultaneous” requests here … so what scenario/problem are you actually trying to prevent here?

Comment: You can of course check whether a file (assuming PHP default storage mechanism is in use here) named according to the session id passed from the client exists in the storage location … but that would still not tell you exactly whether that session was still active. So you would need to look inside, de-serialize the data … and with that you’d be getting so close to what happens when session_start is called, that I’d think twice about how much sense this would still make.

Comment: _“But all subsequent calls will simply block indefinitely”_ - if that is the real, actual issue here – then you might want to look into `session_write_close` perhaps.

Comment: Wow downvote.. ok. I think my question is quite clear. Why do I need to elaborate my motivation? I am astonished that php not seems to support the most basic thing for blocking calls and that is passing a timout value with it :-/

Comment: @04FS Yes, I explicitely want to serialize the requests. One after the other, on per user basis. And I want to deny request if they are too many, too quickly. I hoped to be able to use start_session. I guess not. session_write_close will not help, as it will violate the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

For now my solution is to check if there is already a lock on the session file using exec an shell scripting. **I don't recommend anyone using it who does not fully understand it.**

Basically it tries to get a lock on the session file for the specified timeout value using `flock`. If it fails to do so it exists with 408 Request timeout. (or 429 Too many requests, if available)

For this to work you need to...

1. know your session ID at that point in time
2. have file based sessions

Note, that **this is not atomic**. It still can happen that multiple requests end up waiting in session_start. But it should be a rare event. Most calls should be canceled correctly, which was my agenda.

```
class Session {

    static public function openWhenClosed() {

        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {

            $sessionId = session_id();
            if ($sessionId == null)
                $sessionId = $_COOKIE[session_name()];

            if ($sessionId != null) {
                $sessFile = session_save_path()."/sess_".$sessionId;

                if (file_exists($sessFile)) {
                    $timeout = 30; //How long to try to get hold of the session
                    $fd = 9; //File descriptor to use to try locking the session file.

                    /*
                    * This 'trick' is not atomic!!
                    * After exec returned and session_start() is called there is a time window
                    * where it can happen that other waiting calls get a successful lock and also
                    * proceed and get then blocked by session_start(). The longer the sleep value
                    * the less likely this is to happen. But also the longer the extra delay
                    * for the call
                    */
                    $sleep = "0.01"; //10ms

                    //Check if session file is already locked by trying to get a lock on it.
                    //If it is, try again for $timeout seconds every $sleep seconds
                    exec("
                                exec $fd>>$sessFile;
                                while [ \$SECONDS -lt $timeout ]; do
                                    flock -n $fd;
                                    if [ \$? -eq 0 ]; then exit 0; fi;
                                    sleep $sleep;
                                done;
                                exit 1;
                            ", $null, $timedOut);



                    if ($timedOut) {
                        http_response_code(408); //408: Request Timeout. Or even better 429 if your apache supports it

                        die("Request canceled because another request is still running");
                    }
                }
            }

            session_start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional thoughts:**

1. It is tempting to use `flock -w <timeout>` but that way far more
   waiting in line calls will manage to use the time between `exec` and
   `start_session` to obtain a lock and end up blocking in
   `session_start`
2. If you use the browser for testing this, be aware that most browsers do command queing and reuse a limited amount of connectiosn. So they do not start sending your request before others finish. This can lead to seemingly strange results if you are not aware of this. You can more reliably test using several parallel `wget` commands.
3. I do not recommend to activate this for normal browser request. As mentioned in 2) this is already handled by the browser anyway in most cases. I only use it to protect my API against rouge implementations that do not wait for an answer before sending the next request.
4. The performance hit was negligible in my tests for my overall load. But I would advice to test in your environment yourself using `microtime()` calls